# linear functions on linear space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the linear functions $l_1, l_2, \ldots , l_k$ is given on a linear space $V$ over an infinite field, and $l_1 (x) \cdot l_2 (x) \cdot \ldots  \cdot l_k (x) = 0$ $\forall $x$ \in V$. Prove that then some of these functions are zero.

and specifie pleases if the condition of infinite field is important

Comment: Besides this raw homework text, don't you feel the necessity to add something **of your own**: "I have tried this, I am blocked there..."

Comment: I have proved that there existes a $\alpha \in V$ such that:

   $\alpha \notin V_1,V_2,...,V_s$

Comment: What do you mean by $V_1, V_2, \cdots V_s$ ? And what is $s$ ?

Comment: $V_1 \subsetneq V,V_2 \subsetneq V,...V_s \subsetneq V$ be $s$ proper subspace of $V$,

Comment: What is the connection with $\ell_1,\ell_2 \cdots$ ?

Comment: I don't know, also I've tried to prove that it is needed at least 1 zero function to obtain 0 at the end

Comment: There is an evident possibility: define $V_k:=Ker(\ell_k)$.

Comment: so it is possible to make a relation with what I wrote

Comment: and if there is none of these linear functions vanishing,we consider $V_i = ker(l_i)$ and $V_i$ is a $\textbf{proper}$ subspace of $V$.

Comment: but I still can make a relation with what I wrote?

Comment: and can you please tell is the condition of infinite field is important?

Comment: I am sorry but I am completely puzzled by the way you tackle things: it looks in a so reversed order of the logical order (I noticed already this in your discussion about Jordan blocks yesterday)... First of all, are you sure that you have well copied the question: is it "finite field" or "finite dimensional vectore space" ?"

Comment: I copied because I didn't find the complete explanation

Comment: The fact that it is an infinite field is to be taken in a second step. I advise you to begin by proving your exercice in the case of $V=\mathbb{R^n}$, and yes your finding about $\alpha$ that does not belong to any $V_k$ is a main step. But I will end there by a general advice: **think and write mathematics in a logical way.**

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll try to do my best